# Error al desplegar mi aplicación en heroku

Tags: python, linux, heroku

¿Por qué me muestra un "Application Error" al desplegar mi aplicación en heroku?

Ya llevo rato buscando solución a este problema y no dado con alguna que me funcione. Ya cambie el archivo Procfile, edite los puertos en la aplicación flask que es el framework que uso para las rutas e incluso hice un proyecto mucho más simple y tampoco funciona.

Este es el log de heroku en la terminal, después de estas lineas se repiten los mismos mensajes una y otra vez.

```
2022-08-19T19:57:52.450206+00:00 app[web.1]: Address already in use
2022-08-19T19:57:52.450211+00:00 app[web.1]: Port 5000 is in use by another program. Either identify and stop that program, or start the server with a different port.
2022-08-19T19:57:52.450406+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-19 19:57:52 +0000] [5019] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5019)
2022-08-19T19:57:52.511167+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-19 19:57:52 +0000] [5020] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5020
2022-08-19T19:57:52.659210+00:00 app[web.1]: * Serving Flask app 'app'
2022-08-19T19:57:52.659214+00:00 app[web.1]: * Debug mode: off
2022-08-19T19:57:52.661271+00:00 app[web.1]: Address already in use
2022-08-19T19:57:52.661272+00:00 app[web.1]: Port 5000 is in use by another program. Either identify and stop that program, or start the server with a different port.
```

Aquí el código de prueba en flask que utilizo

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "<h1>Hola mundo</h1>"

app.run(port = 5000)
```

Si tienen alguna solución se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Hola. Los puertos los provee heroku. Tienes que recibirlo con una variable de ambiente.

Comment: Prueba con esta linea: `port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))`

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda pero tampoco funcionó . Salen los mismos mensajes pero esta vez hay un error de tipo H12.

Comment: Puedes actualizar tu pregunta con el nuevo error?

Comment: Es algo extraño, ahora no me aparece pero de todos modos no ejecuta la app. El error decía algo como "H12 (Request Timeouts)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya pudo resolver el problema y todo ejecuta bien. Solo me faltaba agregar la línea de código correspondiente al condicional que obliga al programa a ejecutarse solo si es llamado desde su archivo principal, no pensé que por eso fuese a dar problemas pero ya está todo resulto

El programa de prueba quedaría así

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "<h1>Hola mundo</h1>"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port = 5000)
```